# I keep getting a "secure connection with this site cannot be verified" prompt even after I click no

Tags: windows-7, windows, certificate

Everyone once in a while, seems like every time I wake my computer from sleep, I get the following prompt:

[image]

I have said no several times already, but it keeps coming back.

When I click view certificate I get the following:

[image]

A certificate from ilearnmath.com. I looked the site up, seems legit, but I dont think Ive ever gone there before. More importantly, I dont want to accept their certificate since I have no business with them.

How can I either (a) find the source of this prompt and delete it or (b) tell the prompt no for good?

Comment: Go to certificate path, find the path, then delete the .cert file.

Comment: If you look at the valid period of the certificate, it's very likely that it expired after waking up.
As to why your computer is trying to make connections to this site... me no know. Check if you have any malware/adware/toolbars. You can download malwarebytes for free and scan your system. Also check your installed software. If you install free software from the internet, it often comes with adware that builds itself into your browser... and Internet Explorer is really notorious for that! Try to swich to Firefox or Google Chrome for more safety.

Comment: The error is quite specific about the issue -- the name in the certificate doesn't match the name of the site your browser was trying to retrieve information from.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes.... I know why its here... thats not what I asked. I asked how do I get rid of it. Please read fully next time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue begin around a week ago and it turns out it's an exploit in jusched.exe, the old Java Update service. I was on Java 7 update 21, which was almost a year out-of-date, but after updating to the latest version, the pop-ups went away.

Comment: Can you post a reference to the exploit?

Comment: Yeah agree this appear to be jusched.exe related.  Same issue on Java 7 update 71.